# Doubt about showing $1+1+2+2+2+2$ is not a class equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Is my proof correct?

If $$1+1+2+2+2+2$$ was a class equation of some group $G$, then for some $x\in G$, $|Cl_G(x)|=2$ and as such, $|C_G(x)|=5$. But, from the class equation we have that $|Z(G)|=2$. As $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $C_G(x)$, this would mean that $2$ divides $5$ a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: yes this is correct.

Comment: What are "$C(X)$" (capital X) and "$Z(x)$"?

Comment: This is correct but not written very clearly. Another argument is that if $|Z(G)| = 2$ then $G/Z(G)$ has order $5$, hence is cyclic, and so it would be abelian. But then $|Z(G)| = 10$, a contradiction. So you can see that the problem with this class equation has little to do with the $2$'s but rather with the $1$'s.